# Typescript Conditional Types Confusion

Tags: typescript, validation, conditional-types, typebox

In this code:

```js
const schemas = {
  foo: {
    date1: {
      display: 'date',
      type: 'date',
    },
    text1: {
      display: 'text',
      type: 'text',
    },
    number1: {
      display: 'number',
      type: 'number',
    },
  },
  bar: {
    date2: {
      display: 'date',
      type: 'date'
    },
    text2: {
      display: 'text',
      type: 'text'
    },
    number2: {
      display: 'number',
      type: 'number'
    }
  },
} as const
    
function schema(schemaType: keyof typeof schemas) {
  const fields = schemas[schemaType]
  
  type NumericColumnKeys = {
    [K in keyof typeof fields]: (typeof fields)[K] extends {
      type: 'number'
    }
      ? K
      : never
  }[keyof typeof fields]
}
```

[Plaground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwAsCmBbAhhGBeGBvAUDDAGYggBcehRMAJmlEgIyUE020CWEADgDZoAnpQDk9RiIA01dlEE8ko8UikyYAX2mykADygsq7Il14DhMEYz2qjMOQtFWoNmprVgArigBGSAE4GbEYm-EKinj7+LrLyihYRvn7RGlop1N5ofqxqygBM2bYhZkoMKqkxDhbKImpu2nr5hsHcoeaWus7lNPZx7da1XQn+jUHsRWHxXonJRD3hU1G11G7qMBgwoJBQavjEHmDAUJzgcIioaAAU8MjoACqxlADWSIIgxHaxb6c3GACUTZtoCROEg+LRMDhrucIABtKF3WIAXWo1B6MAAcl5-JxgABhEB8LxgADSLwhTSIMOJME4YBgz1e7x6X2IILBEERlAuzPerNB4N+VMRMA6SDA4Ip3Qek0iSSWtgA-DBiWoiJQwEgAG7+ZYwhlfHnA-kc-DqIA)

My problem is that 'NumericColumnKeys' resolves to *never*. However, if 'schemas' only has one key, it works correctly, i.e.:

```js
    const schemas = {
      foo: {
        date1: {
          display: 'date',
          type: 'date',
        },
        text1: {
          display: 'text',
          type: 'text',
        },
        number1: {
          display: 'number',
          type: 'number',
        },
      }
    }
    *...*
```

[Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwAsCmBbAhhGBeGBvAUDDAGYggBcehRMAJmlEgIyUE020CWEADgDZoAnpQDk9RiIA01dlEE8ko8UikyYAX2mykADygsq7Il14DhMEYz2qjMOQtFWoNmprVgArigBGSAE4GbEYm-EKinj7+LrLyihYRvn7RGloa+OowGDCgkFBq+MQeYMBQnOBwiKhoABTwyOgAKrGUANZIgiDEdrGdFfUYAJSG2eDQJJxIfLSYOHVVEADac42xALrU1PZIMAByXv6cwADCIHxeYADS7TPDRAsXMJxgMG0dXVu9xBNTEKuU1R8ul9JtMBvdVjBdIwwNNbjQtuEvIkRGp1GoiAB+GAXdEwShgJAAN381HUC1evUB4xBv3SQA)

I am trying to use this code to dynamically generate a validation schema from a configurator object. You can find a full example of what I'm trying to accomplish here: https://github.com/oshox/schema-function-test/blob/main/index.ts
Please feel free to suggest better ways to do this.

I need to be able to extract all of the key names from a sub-object based on their 'type' value and be able to use that to construct a Typebox validator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [conditional type with generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to force TypeScript to process each member of the Fields type individually, rather than as a union.

```ts
function schema(schemaType: keyof typeof schemas) {
 const fields = schemas[schemaType]

 type Fields = typeof fields;

 type NumericColumnKeys<T = Fields> = T extends T ? {
   [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends {
     type: 'number'
   }
     ? K
     : never
 }[keyof T] : never;

}
```